# FreeRadius filter_username

Tags: freeradius, radius

I need to adjust the filter to a radius in order to allow a connection only with the username which contains the word "test".

Set up the block:

```
filter_private  {
            if (User-Name =~ /^(?!test).*$/) {
                    update reply {
                            Reply-Message += "Rejected: Username rejected, because not test"
                    }
                    reject
            }
    }
```

But it allows absolutely any username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://networkradius.com/doc/3.0.10/unlang/regex.html), I think you need to negate the logic:

```
if (User-Name !~ /^(?!test).*$/) {
    # etc.
}
```

Also, the regex above probably (depending on your local regex engine) allows usernames *starting* with `test` (due to `^`) not any username *containing* `test`. For the latter, you would need to change the logic to be:

```
if (User-Name !~ /.*test.*/) {
    # etc.
}
```